# EntityFramework Core 2.0 columns naming convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I use TPH in my EntityFramework project with basic structure, expl:

```
public class A
{
  public int Prop1 { .. }
}

public class DerivedB : A 
{
  public int Prop2 { .. }
}
```

EntityFramework by default looks for column named DerivedB_Prop2 so I get an exception: column w.DerivedB_Prop2 does not exist.

I have to manualy configure it in DbContext - OnModelCreating for each property.

builder.Property(p => p.Prop2).HasColumnName("Prop2");

Is there any option how to disable/modify this naming convention globally?

Thanks!

Comment: This happens only if more than one derived entities define property with the same name.

Comment: Yes sir. I can confirm that now. My model was not that easy to find out at first glance. Thank you!